# How to create a Release in Azure release & trigger it from Azure Pipeline?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I am trying scenario, where I have a Azure Build pipeline, where I need to Create a release in Azure Release, then to trigger the release. So that I don't have to wait to complete the Build pipeline to over to start the release.

**Cause:-** I need to run some of the test case run, post deployment of the latest code, I need to start the test suite run from Azure pipeline task.

**Note:-** I had done it using Octopus Task from pipeline. So for Azure release trying the same is possible or not? I am not trying to maintain 2 pipeline, i.e., 1 for build & release & another 1 for running the test Suite.

Comment: Usually the unit tests are added to the build pipeline and if those fail you should exit your building procedure. If those are integration tests you could add them as a separate stage before the release procedure. If those are successful then you can proceed with release otherwise it will be stopped.

Comment: In that case , if i need to run the Integration test on the Latest code changes? how to handle the scenario?

Comment: You can either add the integration tests as a stage after the building procedure, or in a stage before the release procedure. Its up to your choice.